# Descriptive Geometry : Finding symmetric of a point with regards to a plane.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, projection

Consider points $O(0,0,0)$ $A (0,0,2)$ $B (0,6,0)$ $C (4,0,0)$
The problem asks to draw the points using two-dimensional representation and construct the symmetric point D of O with regards to plane ABC with no calculations involved.

Help Appreciated!

Comment: $D$ is also the symmetric of point $O$ with respect to the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$ .

Comment: Are calculations like identifying $d^2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ allowed?